# javascript - Why do I get a &nbsp; if I script &#32;?

Tags: javascript, cursor, whitespace, space, execcommand

I having hard time to insert a single space at the end of my `</span>` in a `document.execCommand()`.

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span class='own-class2'>"+"Test"+"</span>");
```

**The reason behind this is I want the cursor to be outside the `<span>` after having made the insertion.**

Here is a simple jsFiddle to show you what I mean:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgpcy7vo/6/)
In that example, if you click the image and then write something, the text will be green. That means the text is still inside the span.

So What I want is to insert a normal space after `</span>`.

What I have already tried:

- a space like this `'</span> '` -> I get no space in Chrome.
- a space like this `'</span>&#32;'` -> I get `</span>&nbsp;` in Chrome

So my question is how to add a single space in order to get a result equivalent to this `'</span>&#32;'` or `'</span> '` **and not** `'</span>&nbsp;'` ?

### WHAT I GET ON THE INSPECTOR :  https://ibb.co/cqCW2x

if I do :

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span class='own-class2'>"+"Test"+"</span>&#32;");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the zero width no break space character (invisible character) : `\uFEFF`.

The advantage of this solution is it does not create an (maybe?) unwanted visible space after the span

```js
function Test() {
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<span class='own-class2'>"+"Test"+"</span>\uFEFF");
}
```

```css
#textBox {
 width: 540px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px #000000 solid;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: scroll;
}
.own-class2 {color:green;}
```

```html
<div id="toolBar">  
 <button height="20px" onclick="Test()" >insert a span</button>
</div>
<div id="textBox" class="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: @Morse My pleasure :) don't forget to mark your question solved, to help other people

Comment: of course. I have to still wait 5min, but I keep that tab opened to click it... Thanks again that was a real issue..